# How to make :confirm in link_to working with I18n.t() in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

The following `:confirm` pops up a window asking 'Delete the record?':

```
<%= link_to t('Delete'), misc_definition_path(@misc_definition), :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Delete the record?'
```

If adding I18n.t() to the message, however the confirm window does not pop up:

```
<%= link_to t('Delete'), misc_definition_path(@misc_definition), :method => :delete, :confirm => I18n.t('Delete the record?')
```

I tried "#{I18n.t()}" and not working. Is there a way the message can be I18n.t?

Comment: does that I18n key exist? If not, I imagine it would render some really invalid HTML that would prevent the code from working as expected.

Comment: syntax is ok, so it should be something with your key. Now, in general I recommend agains keys like "Delete the record?". I would take something like "messages.confirm_delete" as key...

Comment: Both of you are right! There is no key in yml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is correct.

```
Try this -
 Add some key in your config/locales/*.yml
 confirm_delete: 'Delete Record'
```

Use this key as-

`<%= link_to t('Delete'), misc_definition_path(@misc_definition), :method => :delete, :confirm => I18n.t('confirm_delete') %>`